# pls check this code for facial recognition it is giving me error

Tags: python

the code is given below

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cam.set(3, 640) 
cam.set(4, 480) 

detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

face_id = input("Enter a Numeric user ID  here:  ")

print("Taking samples, look at camera ....... ")
count = 0

while True:

    ret, img = cam.read()
    converted_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(converted_image, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        count += 1

        
        cv2.imwrite("samples/face." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", converted_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff 
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif count >= 10:
         break

print("Samples taken now closing the program....")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error is

```
(<class 'cv2.error'>, error("OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\\opencv\\modules\\objdetect\\src\\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'\n"), <traceback object at 0x00000218F0515AC0>)
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Abhi_workspace\JarvisGUI\simple generator.py", line 22, in <module>
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(converted_image, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: Hard to say, maybe your camera is unavailable, or unavailable for a first few frames of your program. Try to wrap the function in `try: ... except: ...` block

Comment: Break the problem down into simpler-to-diagnose steps, e.g. 1. does the face recognition work with a single image? 2. Do frames get fed to it correctly, 3) etc.